# Can anybody explain the syntax of (function(){})

Tags: javascript

`function(){alert}`

> VM701:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements
>   require a function name

`(function(){alert})`

I typed in two lines of code in the console. the second line is just the first line in `()`. See what I got? What does `()` do here. Can anybody explain the syntax of it?

Answer (score 2):

The parens tell JavaScript to interpret what ever is between them as an expression.  If the expression is valid, then carry out the instructions in the expression. SO, in this case the parens turn an invalid syntax into a function expression.

All language 
[Primary Expressions](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-primary-expression) are tokenized as [CoveredParenthesizedExpression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-static-semantics-coveredparenthesizedexpression) and [Evaluated](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-grouping-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) as Parenthesized expressions.

[Primary Expressions](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-primary-expression)

> When processing the production
>
> ```
>   PrimaryExpression[Yield] : CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList[?Yield]
> ```
>
> the
>   interpretation of CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList is
>   refined using the following grammar:
>
> ```
>    ParenthesizedExpression[Yield] : ( Expression[In, ?Yield] )
> ```

[CoveredParenthesizedExpression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-static-semantics-coveredparenthesizedexpression)

> Static Semantics: CoveredParenthesizedExpression
>
> ```
>  CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList[Yield] : (Expression[In, ?Yield] )
> ```
>
> Return the result of parsing the lexical
>   token stream matched by
>   `CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList[Yield]` using either
>   `ParenthesizedExpression` or `ParenthesizedExpression[Yield]` as the goal
>   symbol depending upon whether the [Yield] grammar parameter was
>   present when `CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList` was
>   matched.

[Evaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-grouping-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) of Parenthesized expressions.

> Runtime Semantics: Evaluation
>
> ```
> PrimaryExpression : CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList
> ```
>
> Let `expr` be `CoveredParenthesizedExpression` of
>   `CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList`. Return the result
>   of evaluating `expr`. 
>         `ParenthesizedExpression : ( Expression )`
>
> Return
>   the result of evaluating `Expression`. This may be of type Reference.
>
> NOTE This algorithm does not apply `GetValue` to the result of
>   evaluating Expression. The principal motivation for this is so that
>   operators such as delete and typeof may be applied to parenthesized
>   expressions.

Answer (score 0):

This type of functions are called anonymous functions, and usually are assigned to a variable:

```
var fun1 = function(){ ... }
```

assigns an anonymous function to the variable fun1.

```
fun1

[Function: fun1]
```

so when you put the parenthesis, you are executing that function.

If you wrap it, javascript evaluates it as a function:

```
(function(){ ... })

[Function]
```

You cal also execute it in the same moment wrapping the function with parenthesis:

```
(function(){ ... })()
```

If you do not put a name , assign it or execute it, you will not be able to execute it later, and javascript will throw an error.